# Recursive discriminated union case types

Tags: f#, ocaml, record, abstract-syntax-tree, discriminated-union

How can I create OCaml/F# DU type where its cases are subsets of other cases?

For example, I want to make a symbol table which contains different symbol declaration types, such as program types, variables and functions.

At first glance, I can see that a variable contains its type, function also contains a type and many parameter variables. So I'd like to use 1 DU, instead of seperating to many records or aliases:

```
type Symbol =
    | TypeSymbol of id:string
    | VariableSymbol of id:string * type':TypeSymbol
    | FunctionSymbol of id:string * params':VariableSymbol list * type':TypeSymbol
```

But this is wrong, because the DU cases cannot be subsets of other cases. How can I reformat types to declare that DU cases are recursive to each other?

Comment: (For what it's worth, OCaml and F# are not the same language. The code you give is not valid OCaml. But it's clear what you're asking.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For F#, the simplest solution would be to create smaller single-case DUs and reference those:

```
type T = T of id:string
type V = V of id:string * type':T
type Symbol =
   | TypeSymbol of T
   | VariableSymbol of V
   | FunctionSymbol of id:string * params': V list * type':T
```

Its usage through decomposition could be something like this.

```
let rec print x = 
   match x with
   | TypeSymbol (T typeId) -> 
      typeId

   | VariableSymbol (V (varId, T typeId)) -> 
      sprintf "%s : %s" varId typeId

   | FunctionSymbol (funId, params', T typeId) ->         
      let printedParams = 
         params'
         |> List.map (VariableSymbol >> print) 
         |> String.concat ") -> ("
      sprintf "%s = (%s) -> %s" funId printedParams typeId
```

Comment: It is possible to use the keyword **type** together with **and** for recursive types See https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recursive-types-and-folds-1b/

Answer (score 6):

I've never used them but I think you want to work with GADT (*this answer is for OCaml*):

```
type ts
type vs
type 'a symbol =
  | TypeSymbol : {id : string} -> ts symbol
  | VariableSymbol : {id : string; ty : ts symbol} -> vs symbol
  | FunctionSymbol : {id : string; params : vs symbol; ty : ts symbol} -> 'a symbol;;

(*don't use "type" as a field name since it's a keyword of OCaml*)
```

As you can see, this allows me to specify exactly with what constructors I build my constructors.

Now, when I want to use them :

```
# let t = TypeSymbol {id = "a"};;
val t : ts symbol = TypeSymbol {id = "a"}
# let v = VariableSymbol {id = "b"; ty = t};;
val v : vs symbol = VariableSymbol {id = "b"; ty = TypeSymbol {id = "a"}}
# let ve = VariableSymbol {id = "c"; ty = v};;
Characters 41-42:
  let ve = VariableSymbol {id = "c"; ty = v};;
                                          ^
Error: This expression has type vs symbol
       but an expression was expected of type ts symbol
       Type vs is not compatible with type ts
```

As you can see, OCaml will not allow me to create a symbol with the constructor `VariableSymbol` if I try to build it with something else than a `TypeSymbol`.

See [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual021.html#toc85) for the manual and good luck in using them.

Comment: it's tricky indeed to use gadts, but doable if you consider continuations.

Comment: It's tricky indeed but the fact is it looked like he wanted to have no external type like in piaste's answer and I couldn't think about another solution.

Comment: Sure, I was just wondering about the "good luck" part in your answer, which seemed to suggest it would be very difficult to get it done.

Comment: Oh no, it's just that when you get used to never write the types, gadts are not your best friends. ;-)

Comment: oh, I get it now :)